# symfony override parameter per testcase

Tags: symfony

Let's say I have a class that does something only for particular routes, those route names are stored in `service.yaml`

```
parameters:
    supported_routes: ['route1', 'route2']
```

and I want to write a few test cases:

- testIgnoreRoute1IfRouteNotSupported - where I want to change that `supported_routes` list to exclude `route1`
- testIgnoreRoute2IfRouteNotSupported - where I want to change that `supported_routes` list to exclude `route2`
- testPerformActionIfRoute1Supported - where I want to have `route1` in `supported_routes`
- testPerformActionIfRoute2Supported - where I want to have `route2` in `supported_routes`

How can I do that with Symfony??? It's not allowed to change container parameters on the fly as the container is frozen. It's possible to override `service.yaml` with the test `service.yaml` but in that case, it still will be the same list for all tests even if it can be different from the main list. Also, it's possible to store that list in env, but I do not think it's a good idea as I do not want it to depend on env in a real app.

I know you can tell me why don't you write a unit test and mock what you need. It's not as easy as in my real application that list is used by third-party libraries as a part of library configuration so it should be integration/functional test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of at the moment is the following. I am not sure if I have understood your question correctly.

You could define different environments for the test and call them up accordingly.

**service.yaml**

```yaml
when@test: &route_test
    parameters:
        supported_routes: ['route1', 'route2']

when@testroute1:
    framework:
        test: true
    parameters:
        supported_routes: ['route1']


when@testroute2:
    framework:
        test: true
    parameters:
        supported_routes: ['route2']
```

With `APP_ENV=<envname> php bin/phpunit --filter ServiceTest` you start the test accordingly.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Tests\SO77229710;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;

class ServiceTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var ParameterBagInterface
     */
    private mixed $parameters;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        self::bootKernel();
        $this->parameters = self::getContainer()->get(ParameterBagInterface::class);
    }

    /**
     * APP_ENV=testroute1 php bin/phpunit --filter ServiceTest
     */
    public function testRoute1()
    {
        if ('testroute1' !== self::$kernel->getEnvironment()) {
            $this->markTestSkipped('Skipped because is not APP_EN testroute1');
        }

        $this->assertEquals(['route1'], $this->parameters->get('supported_routes'));
    }

    /**
     * APP_ENV=testroute2 php bin/phpunit --filter ServiceTest
     */
    public function testRoute2()
    {
        if ('testroute2' !== self::$kernel->getEnvironment()) {
            $this->markTestSkipped('Skipped because is not APP_EN testroute2');
        }

        $this->assertEquals(['route2'], $this->parameters->get('supported_routes'));
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

Set APP_ENV On-the-fly.

```php
class ServiceTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    public function testRoute1()
    {
        self::bootKernel(['environment' => 'testroute1']);
        $parameters = self::getContainer()->get(ParameterBagInterface::class);
        $this->assertEquals(['route1'], $parameters->get('supported_routes'));
    }

    public function testRoute2()
    {
        self::bootKernel(['environment' => 'testroute2']);
        $parameters = self::getContainer()->get(ParameterBagInterface::class);
        $this->assertEquals(['route2'], $parameters->get('supported_routes'));
    }
}
```

Comment: well, I can but it looks very ugly, I mean I'm providing a lot of different environments which are overhead, I'm looking for a way to override parameters without such complexity

Comment: You will not get around the ENV configurations. You can set APP_ENV during the test. See my Update.